# Excel VBA - Passing argument to a function

Tags: vba, excel, range, parameter-passing

I attempted to create an Excel function that will bold whatever range I tell it to in whatever form I request. Unfortunately, I've only had partial success in correctly passing the variable and obtaining this outcome. Of course, nobody likes a partial so can someone please let me know what I'm missing.

```
Sub Macro1()
On Error Resume Next

'Create & reset testing area.
   Range("A1:C6").value = "A"
   Range("A1:C6").Font.Bold = False
   [b2].Select

'The two lines below call the function perfectly and the cells are bolded without issue
   Text_bold ([a1])
   Text_bold (Cells(2, 1))

'However, the party stops there as the following code errors out.
   Text_bold ([b1].Address)
   Text_bold (Selection)
   Text_bold (Range("B3"))
'Similarly, the below fails as well...
   Text_bold (Range("B4:C4"))
'And even less surprising, the following also refuses to assist in the endeavor...
   Text_bold (Application.Union(Range("B5:C5"), Range("B6:C6")))
End Sub

Function Text_bold(x As Range)
   'MsgBox VarType(x)
   x.Font.Bold = True
End Function
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses around your function parameters are causing the problem. They are forcing the enclosed value to be evaluated before being passed as the function parameter, passing a Range.Value instead of Range object.

```
Sub Macro1()
    On Error Resume Next

     'Create & reset testing area.
    Range("A1:C6").Value = "A"
    Range("A1:C6").Font.Bold = False
    [b2].Select

    'The two lines below call the function perfectly and the cells are bolded without issue
    Text_bold [a1]
    Text_bold Cells(2, 1)

    'However, the party stops there as the following code errors out.
    Text_bold Range([C1].Address)
    Text_bold Selection.Range
    Text_bold Range("B3")
    'Similarly, the below fails as well...
    Text_bold Range("B4:C4")
    'And even less surprising, the following also refuses to assist in the endeavor...
    Text_bold Application.Union(Range("B5:C5"), Range("B6:C6"))
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

If you really want to use parentheses, prefix your function with Call statement.

```
Call Text_bold(Application.Union(Range("B5:C5"), Range("B6:C6")))
```

Comment: For more understanding, I think it's helpful to note that the lines that are failing are failing because the Range object is providing Range.Value instead of being passed as the object itself

Comment: @serafalcon, yes noted. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you'll get syntax error if you try to call a multiple parameter function with parentheses without Call, like:  FunctionX (param1, param2)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get more details about the issue you need to remove the statement
`On Error Resume Next` (aka **`On Error Hide All Bugs`**)

After I removed it I was able to determine the problems

- The function (which should be a Sub because it doesn't return a value) is expecting a Range object: `Text_bold(`**x As Range**`)`
- the line `Text_bold ([b1].Address)` is calling it incorrectly with parenthesis, and it is attempting to send as argument a string, not a range
- all your calls to the function should be without brackets

Try this:

---

```
Sub Macro1()
    'Create & reset testing area.
    Range("A1:C6").Value = "A"
    Range("A1:C6").Font.Bold = False
    [b2].Select

    Text_bold [a1]
    Text_bold Cells(2, 1)
    Text_bold [b1]
    Text_bold Selection
    Text_bold Range("B3")
    Text_bold Range("B4:C4")
    Text_bold Application.Union(Range("B5:C5"), Range("B6:C6"))

    'A sub cannot return a value, a function can but it doesn't have to

    'To return a value from the Text_bold function
    Dim functionResponse As Boolean

    functionResponse = Text_bold([B3])  '<- THIS is where you need to use brackets
    MsgBox "Text in Cell [B3] is bold: " & functionResponse

End Sub

Function Text_bold(x As Range) As Boolean
    x.Font.Bold = True
    Text_bold = (x.Font.Bold = True)    'assign the return value to the function name
End Function
```